# Merge elements of a list to a single element in java arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, merge, collections, addition

I have an arraylist of String.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have added 2 elements to the list.

```
list.add("text1");
list.add("text2");
```

The output is like this.

```
[text1,text2]
```

But I need an output as below.

```
[text1 text2]
```

i.e., both elements should be merged and placed in a single index.
Could someone help on this?

Comment: Are you aware of [`String.join(delimiter, elements)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.Iterable))? Add square brackets using concatenation if you need them `"[" + String.join(" ", list ) + "]"`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko read the last sentence of the question.

Comment: @f1sh *"both elements should be merged and placed in a single index"* - it's very obscuring and ambiguous. If OP wants the list to contain only a **single** element, and then it'll be better to join all elements and then create a singleton list. If OP wants to merge only consecutive pairs of elements, that's doable as well, but some **clarifications are required**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To everyone who didn't read the question completely, this is the last sentence: "both elements should be merged and placed in a single index".

You can just create the merged `String` and create a new List with one entry:

```
List<String> result = List.of(list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

If you need to reduce the existing `List` down to one element, you can keep adding each subsequent element to the first one using this loop:

```
list.add("text1");
list.add("text2");
list.add("text3");
list.add("text4");
while(list.size() > 1) {
    list.set(0, list.get(0) +" "+ list.remove(1));
}
System.out.println(list);
```

prints `[text1 text2 text3 text4]`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Instead of String if we are using class object how can we do it?

Comment: You cannot place multiple `Object`s into one `List` element. This is possible for `String` values because you can combine multiple `String`s into one by appending them. You could also reduce multiple numerical values by adding/multiplying them into one value. How do you imagine multiple `Object`s could be combined? Or is it just about combining their `String` representations?

Answer (score -2):

You can do it like this.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("text1");
    list.add("text2");

    list.set(0, String.join(",", list).replace(",", " "));

    list.subList(1, list.size()).clear();

    System.out.println(list.size());
    System.out.println(list);
```

Output of this is:

1

[text1 text2]